# Resolution of CATextLayer

Tags: ios, ipad

I am trying to develop an IOS app which is listing a set of texts in different sizes and allows the user to zoom in and view smaller items.I am using CATextLayer inside CAShapelayer to draw a text and this this added to a UIVIew ,which again is added to a UIScrollView.While Scrolling I am returning the UIView object in "viewForZoomingInScrollView" delegate method.
Now the issue is that the text in  CATextlayer becomes blurred when zooming in .Is it possible to set the resolution or aspect ratio to keep the clarity of smaller texts while zooming...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to zoom in, then the text layer will loose clarity.
You could draw the layers in higher resolution then zoom out to fit the view.

This way you will allow the user to zoom in only to the maximum of 1:1 scale, which will allow the TextLayer to keep it's clarity.

Of course, I assume you are already setting the contentScale of the layer to match the screens scale (retina display). Right?